# google apps script on form submit update calendar slow response

Tags: forms, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a simple booking system on google calendar. However, users feel complicated, so I made a google form as a front end to simplify the data entry.

The process is straight forward. It's just form, sheets and then apps script. There is no functional problem.

There is performance issue.

The total time from Form submit to calendar update shown on browser takes in average 30 seconds. The time stamp on execution script shown less than one second to complete the apps script but it take more than ten second to start apps script. It means there is more than ten seconds for google form and sheets to complete and more than ten seconds for calendar to sync.

Any advice to shorten total processing time?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Thomason

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You cannot change how Google runs its network or servers to sync information. You can only make Apps Script run faster, by using best practices. Otherwise, you are at the mercy of Google.